# Vscode: How can I config "open new tab (editor)" keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a shortcut to open a untitled blank tab (editor) in Vscode (version 1.28.1) instead of moving the mouse and double-click the upper bound of Vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of main *default* short-cuts at **Help/ Keyboard Shortcut Reference**.

Additionally, you can find the command at **View/ Command Palette**. Type e.g. `new` and you'll see the `File: New Untitle File` command together with *current* short-cut.

[image: Command Palette: new]

Comment: Thanks :) This is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can open a new tab by creating a new file ("Command + n" on Mac, "Ctrl + n" on windows). The file won't be saved to disk until you do it manually.

Comment: Yeap that is what I am looking for. Thanks :)